# Jenkins Workflow building a new job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying make a parameterized build of a new job from my existing job as follows:

I tried both ways:

```
build('NEXT-DEPLOY-JOB', PARAM_FROM_BUILD:'1.4', DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT: "QA")
```

and without paranthesis way:

```
build 'NEXT-DEPLOY-JOB', PARAM_FROM_BUILD:'1.4', DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT: "QA"
```

However in both cases I receive such error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{PARAM_FROM_BUILD=1.4, DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=QA4}, NEXT-DEPLOY-JOB]
```

Please tell me, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax quoted by @Jayan will work, but is deprecated. (And the Workflow syntax has nothing to do with persistence of state.)

Use *Snippet Generator* to see an example of the right syntax, tailored to the parameter types expected by the particular downstream job you are triggering.

Comment: When I use the snippet generator in 2.0 pipelines, I get something like `build('trunk/checkout', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PIPELINE_ID', value: env.BUILD_ID]])`, and I still get this error (`Expected named arguments but got [{parameters=[{$class=StringParameterValue, name=PIPELINE_ID, value=16}]}, trunk/checkout]`).

Comment: You forgot `job:`. Read the tutorial.

Comment: The point was that that code came straight out of the snippet generator, as-is (except for the `env.BUILD_ID`). I didn't remove a 'job:` parameter. So recommending the snippet generator is not enough.

Comment: Hmm, if the generator really produced what you claim, that is certainly a bug; if you can, file it with _exact_ details to reproduce, including plugin versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below( as I learnt from @Jesse Glick, it is deprecated..)

```
build job: 'NEXT-DEPLOY-JOB', parameters: [new hudson.model.StringParameterValue('PARAM_FROM_BUILD', '1.4'),
hudson.model.StringParameterValue('DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT', 'QA')
]
```